# Flash Develop - Publishing

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am using Flash Develop, and I have created an ActionScript 3.0 project.  It starts and read an xml file, which contain urls to images.  I have left the urls relative to the same folder as the swf.  OK, so I publish and I have a compiled SWF and this is inside the bin folder.  If I then copy this folder, e.g. to by publish folder, the swf does not start, I get no warning or anything and I have literally copy and pasted the bin folder which contains the compiled swf.  I have checked the swf and it contains all packages I have created.  Anyone have any idea on why this would not play when I have copied the bin folder else where?

Cheers,

Andrew

Comment: I should mention ofcourse that it works fine once published.  it is when I copy and paste the bin folder else where that it will just not start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to tell Adobe Flash Player that your application is trusted, i.e. it can access local files.  That's only necessary when you access your flash program with the file:// protocol; once you upload it to a web server it will work smoothly.

To grant local access rights to a flash program, open `My Documents\Application Data\Macromedia\Flash Player\#Security\FlashPlayerTrust\` directory, create a text file called `<MyFlashApp>.cfg`, and paste the directory path containing your flash program into this file.  Thus this file should cointain a single line, trailing backslash is not required.  (I don't know what the Unix counterpart of this path is.)

FlashDevelop automatically does this for you for each flash project that you create.