# Flash not interacting with Javascripts in browser inside my app

Tags: javascript, flash, security, xulrunner

I have an application which embeds a `xulrunner` based browser.

I have to load some flash content in it which talks to some javascript  to update 
the browser title.

The flash content works fine when launched from Firefox but not inside my app. I tried a sample html file which has some javascript and they work fine. It even works when I have the flash content on a server. It is only when I try to run js through flash present on my local machine that I see this problem.

I guess it must have something to do with some security settings in `xulrunner`.
 Could somebody help me figure out what the problem might be?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542747/flash-develop-publishing/542879#542879), it might the solution of your problems.

Comment: I have the flash player trust file and I have the appropriate entries in the file. The location for the file on unix is /etc/adobe/FlashPlayerTrust . But still it doesn't work. I have added the path to my application also in the trust file to make sure that my application is also trused.

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the browser title from within the application itself...

```
import mx.managers.IBrowserManager;
import mx.managers.BrowserManager;

private var bm:IBrowserManager = BrowserManager.getInstance();
bm.init("", "New Browser Title");
```